# Why can I use the global function fetch after the src is bundled with webpack? Although I haven't included the fetch module in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, fetch

I am confused about the usage of `fetch`in webpack.

As long as I pack the `fetch` with webpack, an error occurs, but when I remove the `fetch` module from webpack, it works as well.

Comment: Did you try `node-fetch` on npm?

Comment: I've not tried that ，but I import the  dependent module fetch I've installed before

Comment: Because [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is an official API that is supported by all modern browsers (present on `window.fetch`)

Comment: @nem035 it's probably a reason,I should test it in other  out of date browsers.but why there is a fetch module in npm?what is it for?

Comment: The fetch module on npm is just a polyfill for environments that do not have the fetch api.

Comment: @nem035 thank your patience to my question,I am a new to this website,because of my worse English

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are able to use fetch even though you didn't include it in your bundle is because fetch is an [official API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) that is supported by all modern browsers:

```js
console.log(
  typeof window.fetch // function on modern browsers
);
```

The main reason people install a npm package with the same API is to handle environments without a built-in `fetch` API, such as older browsers.

Comment: I've installed it ,but I haven't packed it into bundle.js with webpack

Comment: @user7980590 does not really make a difference but I've updated my answer :)